# How to find the cause of CancelledError in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a big project which depends some third-party libraries, and sometimes its execution gets interrupted by a CancelledError.

To demonstrate the issue, let's look at a small example:

```py
import asyncio


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(foo())

    # Cancel the task in 1 second.
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(1.0, lambda: task.cancel())

    await task


async def foo():
    await asyncio.sleep(999)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ss/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.2/scratches/async.py", line 19, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

As you can see, there's no information about the place the CancelledError originates from. How do I find out the exact cause of it?

One approach that I came up with is to place a lot of try/except blocks which would catch the CancelledError and narrow down the place where it comes from. But that's quite tedious.

Comment: That's not the complete traceback for me. The parts including and before ``During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`` are *also* part of the traceback.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, this is actually all the traceback that I see. Tested with python 3.7. Could you post the traceback that you see?

Comment: [It's rather a bit longer](https://gist.github.com/maxfischer2781/4228ffed05981b0e17960055892a363f). While it was recorded with Python 3.9, [chaining exists since 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, thanks. As far as I understand, your traceback shows exactly the source of the cancellation. It's a pity python 3.7 doesn't do this.

Comment: Looks like this only works since 3.9 indeed; 3.8 also removes the chain. I didn't find anything in the changelog, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by applyting a decorator to every async function in the project. The decorator's job is simple - log a message when a CancelledError is raised from the function. This way we will see which functions (and more importantly, in which order) get cancelled.

Here's the decorator code:

```py
def log_cancellation(f):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return await f(*args, **kwargs)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print(f"Cancelled {f}")
            raise
    return wrapper
```

In order to add this decorator everywhere I used regex. Find: `(.*)(async def)`. Replace with: `$1@log_cancellation\n$1$2`.

Also to avoid importing `log_cancellation` in every file I modified the builtins:
`builtins.log_cancellation = log_cancellation`

Answer (score 1):

The `rich` package has helped us to identify the cause of `CancelledError`, without much code change required.

```
from rich.console import Console

console = Console()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())  # replace main() with your entrypoint
    except BaseException as e:
        console.print_exception(show_locals=True)
```